# Trying to get Hadoop working in pseudo-distributed mode: connection refused and other errors

Tags: hadoop, ssh, hdfs

I have installed Hadoop 2.7.3 on my Linux Mint 17.1 machine and am following the Apache [tutorial](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html) to get it running. I have been following the instructions on this page closely and have gotten to the point where I can ssh into `localhost` and run `start-dfs.sh` and `start-yarn.sh`. I have also formatted the name node.

My core-site.xml file is edited according to the tutorial:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

As is hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

However, running the command `hadoop fs -mkdir /test` gives me the following error:

```
mkdir: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.; Host Details : local host is: "MILTON/127.0.1.1"; destination host is: "localhost":9000;
```

Running jps gives me this output:

```
15388 Jps
14966 ResourceManager
14615 DataNode
15077 NodeManager
14787 SecondaryNameNode
```

Looking in my log files, I see more detailed errorts and warnings that might have to do with this. In hadoop-user-namenode-MILTON.log I see this error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /tmp/hadoop-user/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverStorageDirs(FSImage.java:327)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:975)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:681)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:585)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:645)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:812)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:796)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1559)
```

In hadoop-user-secondarynamenode-MILTON.log I see the full traceback for the exception I was getting on the command line:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.; Host Details : local host is: "MILTON/127.0.1.1"; destination host is: "localhost":9000; 
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getTransactionId(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.NamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getTransactionID(NamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getTransactionID(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.countUncheckpointedTxns(SecondaryNameNode.java:641)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.shouldCheckpointBasedOnCount(SecondaryNameNode.java:649)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.doWork(SecondaryNameNode.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode$1.run(SecondaryNameNode.java:361)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.doAsLoginUserOrFatal(SecurityUtil.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.run(SecondaryNameNode.java:357)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.
    at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidWireType(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:99)
    at com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Builder.mergeFieldFrom(UnknownFieldSet.java:498)
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.parseUnknownField(GeneratedMessage.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto.<init>(RpcHeaderProtos.java:2207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto.<init>(RpcHeaderProtos.java:2165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto$1.parsePartialFrom(RpcHeaderProtos.java:2295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto$1.parsePartialFrom(RpcHeaderProtos.java:2290)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:200)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:241)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:253)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:259)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto.parseDelimitedFrom(RpcHeaderProtos.java:3167)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveRpcResponse(Client.java:1085)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:979)
```

Earlier in the log I also see this exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Call From MILTON/127.0.1.1 to localhost:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:732)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getTransactionId(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.NamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getTransactionID(NamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getTransactionID(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.countUncheckpointedTxns(SecondaryNameNode.java:641)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.shouldCheckpointBasedOnCount(SecondaryNameNode.java:649)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.doWork(SecondaryNameNode.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode$1.run(SecondaryNameNode.java:361)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.doAsLoginUserOrFatal(SecurityUtil.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.run(SecondaryNameNode.java:357)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:744)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:495)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:712)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2900(Client.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1451)
    ... 18 more
```

Meanwhile the datanode log is repeatedly logging messages that look like this:

```
2017-03-14 20:50:37,785 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Problem connecting to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000
```

I also notice that I am unable to access the web interface for the name node as the tutorial suggests; trying to go to `http://localhost:9870/` gives me an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. I'm guessing the name node is not starting at all; when I run stop-dfs.sh it says "localhost: no namenode to stop". What am I doing wrong that is causing the steps in the tutorial to fail for me?

NOTE: I am aware that numerous similar questions have been posted. What they tend to have in common is that they are about setups more complex than mine (e.g. fully distributed mode, not just running the basic tutorial) or they find a solution in doing something differently from the tutorial. I am interested in learning, specifically, why I can't get the tutorial to work for me and fixing that before applying other changes I don't yet understand. Unless the Apache tutorial is really just mistaken.

UPDATE 2017-3-20: I followed franklinsijo's advice and, after adding the properties he recommends and formatting the namenode, I am getting this exception in my namenode log file:

```
java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [localhost:9000] java.net.BindException: Address already in use; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:721)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.bind(Server.java:425)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener.<init>(Server.java:574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.<init>(Server.java:2215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.<init>(RPC.java:951)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server.<init>(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:534)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine.getServer(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:509)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Builder.build(RPC.java:796)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.<init>(NameNodeRpcServer.java:345)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createRpcServer(NameNode.java:674)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:647)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:812)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:796)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1559)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:463)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.bind(Server.java:408)
    ... 13 more
```

Commenting out the "Port 9000" line in my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file doesn't change this exception.

Comment: Namenode is not running..? passwordless-ssh..?

Comment: I can ssh into localhost without a password. (Sorry, didn't make that fully clear above) I'm trying to figure out why namenode is not running, as that seems to be my biggest problem.

Comment: Can you add the `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml` files as well to the post?

Comment: Added--they are exactly what the Apache tutorial says to use for pseudo-distributed mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `hadoop.tmp.dir` is `/tmp/hadoop-${user.name}`.

This `tmp.dir` is used as the base directory for `dfs.namenode.name.dir` as `file://${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/name`. 
The files present in `/tmp` would be lost on reboot. So the namenode directory which was formatted earlier is no more available after reboot.

Without a consistent storage directory, it is not possible to start the `NameNode` daemon. Thus, the exception

```
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /tmp/hadoop-user/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible
```

Either add this property to `core-site.xml`

```
<property>
   <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
   <value>/home/user/dfs</value> <!-- Any directory, other than /tmp, that exists and the user running hadoop has access -->
</property>
```

Or explicitly define the directories for storing metadata and data blocks by adding these properties to `hdfs-site.xml`

```
<property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
   <value>/home/user/dfs/name</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>/home/user/dfs/data</value>
</property>
```

**Note:** You can do both as well.

Then format the `NameNode` and start the services. The other errors are from the services when they are unable to make contact with the `NameNode` daemon (because it is not running). Web Interface will be accessible only if the `NameNode` is alive.

Comment: Why was the tutorial not working--does it assume the machine I'm running on is never rebooted? Anyway, I tried adding these properties and am getting a different exception now; I have added the new traceback to my original question.

Comment: The documentation must contain this property, I can't imagine why they missed it out. The mew exception says, the port is already being used. Stop the cluster once and try restarting it.

Comment: I tried stopping and starting dfs a few times and kept getting the error. Does "stopping the cluster" mean anything else?

Comment: `stop-dfs.sh` should do. If you are still getting the error, it means some other process is using that port. Try changing the port to `8020` instead of `9000` in `core-site.xml`, and restart it.

Comment: That still gives me the same "Address already in use" error. Specifically, I tried changing the port number in core-site.xml, hadoop-env.sh, and my sshd_config file, first to 8020 and then to a totally random port (8368), rerunning `sudo service ssh restart`, and trying to start dfs and make a directory again. Both tries gave me the exact same exception as did port 9000. Am I missing any steps?

Comment: What are you changing in sshd_config and hadoop-env.sh?  Only core-site.xml requires change.

Comment: Having one port number in sshd_config and hadoop-env.sh and a different one in core-site.xml finally works! Thanks!